# How to access Span text of button in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, siebel

I have an element, when inspected shows:

```
<button type="button" class="siebui-ctrl-btn siebui-icon-editresponse s_1_1_126_0 appletButton" id="s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl" name="s_1_1_126_0" data-display="Edit Response" tabindex="0" title="Request: Main Menu:Edit Response" aria-label="Request: Main Menu:Edit Response" data-seq="0">
    <span>Edit Response</span>
</button>
```

I would like to be able to update the span text to "Respond" via jQuery.

I've tried several different things such as:

```
$('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl span').text("Respond");
```

and

```
$(".siebui-ctrl-btn.siebui-icon-editresponse.s_1_1_126_0.appletButton").text("Respond");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you close your button tag properly and check or its a typo?

Comment: Does the button exist when your code runs? `alert($('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl').length)` Also try running that code in browser console and see what happens

Comment: When I start/close the tag properly, the code doesn't show up in my question. It just shows the text "Edit Response".  When the code runs, the button is there.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/c92arL7a/

Comment: Yes. Its working fine. Can you recheck your code. Always try to get a jsfiddle. When do you want to update your text?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a span inside the button in order to use the example you posted. Since there was no span rendered to the page JQuery will not recognize the {ID} span reference.

```
<button><span id="myid">Edit Respond</span></button>

$('#myid').text("Respond");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl span')` is not looking for the span as a child.

So change to this;

`$('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl > span')` will find the span as a child of the button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl > span').text("Respond");
});
```

Comment: statement not accurate and is a bit misleading. All your selector is doing is being more specific to look only for children. OP version will find any span in that element

Comment: I apologize for the misleading wording. The first example should work. But in some applications, it will select the wrong span and try to change that text. So if you are more specific, you are more likely to see the response you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="siebui-ctrl-btn siebui-icon-editresponse s_1_1_126_0 appletButton" id="s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl" name="s_1_1_126_0" data-display="Edit Response" tabindex="0" title="Request: Main Menu:Edit Response" aria-label="Request: Main Menu:Edit Response" data-seq="0">Edit Response</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl').click(function(){
    $('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl').text("Respond");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First, this is not good since there is no span:

```
$('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl span')
```

It should be:

```
$('#s_1_1_126_0_Ctrl')
```

Try and see.

Comment: You might want to look closer at the html...there definitely is a span

Comment: Right; it wasn't properly formatted when I answered.